# Limit point symmetric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $x$ is a limit point of $y$, is $y$ a limit point of $x$? (We are assuming general topological spaces here.)

I am curious under what conditions is this true, or is it always true?

Intuitively it should be true, since if $x$ is close to $y$ then $y$ is close to $x$.

Comment: How are you defining a limit point of a point?

Comment: Assuming your interpretation of $x$ is a limit point of $y$ is that $x$ belongs to the closure of $\{y\}$, the answer is that in an arbitrary topological space $X$ the relation $x\in Cl(y)$ need not imply $y\in Cl(x)$, as is very well-known. Very minimal separation conditions do imply the implication, as is also very well-known.

Comment: How minimal is the separation conditions? Is Hausdorff enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Sierpinski space $S=\{0,1\}$ where $\phi, S,$ and $\{0\}$ are open but $\{1\}$ is not open. Then $1$ is a limit point of $\{0\}$ but $0$ is not a limit point of $\{1\}.$